# Search not working on Careers, and inconsistent favourite count

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, stack-overflow-jobs

I've noticed that maybe a couple of weeks ago, the search functionality has stopped working on Careers.

For example, the titular page says that I have 8 favourites.  When I click on "view all favourites", it only shows 4 instead.

Or, if I try to search for "freebsd", I'm getting no results at all, even though there are a couple of jobs listing it in the description, and at least one listing it as an outright tag.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the bug report!

By default, the job search page won't show jobs that the employer has chosen not to advertise in your region. If you want to see jobs that aren't targeted to your region, you can put something in the Location box.

It looks like there was a bug in the "favourite listings" page. I've tweaked the logic - you should now see all of your favourites.

Comment: What do you mean by "your region"?  The job in question (in SF) is certainly within 100km of the city in my profile (SJ), and is certainly within my "region".  Are you confirming that you discriminate jobs based on IPv4 addresses instead, grouping the network population into arbitrary and hardcoded "regions"?

Comment: @cnst right now, yes we use IPv4 address to determine what advertising region you're in. Plans are afoot to use information in your profile but they're blocked on some other changes.

Comment: @cnst discriminate seems a bit inflammatory, no?

Comment: @DeanWard, no, it's not; it's just saying how it is; and the amount of bugs that this useless, counterintuitive and shady feature presents is simply astonishing; this favourites bug was merely one of the many.