# Narrowing down Careers search by Location returns more (not fewer!) results

Tags: bug, search, stack-overflow-jobs

This makes absolutely no sense -- trying to ***narrow down*** a *Careers* search by specifying a *Location* actually returns *MORE*, instead of *FEWER*, results!

This especially makes no sense when searching for remote work.

On the site overall, there are ***111 remote jobs total***:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Km&allowsremote=true

Yet, ***narrowing it down*** to the United States alone gets you ***278 remote jobs*** (almost three times more than the total number of remote jobs!):

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=United+States&range=20&distanceUnits=Km&allowsremote=true

Europe has 74:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=Europe&range=20&distanceUnits=Km&allowsremote=true

***Does some other region has a negative count that makes 278 + 74 + xx equal 111, e.g., some 4 times fewer jobs than the two most popular regions alone have?***

In other words, since when is the sum of 278 and 74, plus some change from other regions, equal less than either one of the numbers?!

Comment: I think this should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274210/215590

Comment: The only reason that I could see for someone wanting to post Jobs (formerly Careers) questions and answers here would be to try and accrue reputation not available via [meta.so].

Answer (score -1):

It appears that Careers implements some shady filtering of the search results based on the IP address of the client or proxy used to connect to the site.  (And it sounds like it's then cached for job alerts, too.)

It appears to let the employers to filter advertisement based on "region"; this "region", in turn, appears to not at all be related to the *Location* specified in the Careers profile, but is instead derived from the IP-address alone.

[Benjamin Hodgson♦ says yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316242/1122270):

> By default, the job search page won't show jobs that the employer has chosen not to advertise in your region. If you want to see jobs that aren't targeted to your region, you can put something in the Location box.

Comment: We recently released a change that picks up advertising countries from your CV and locations that you state you have a visa for. We fallback to geo-location if you don't have either of those fields populated.